# Use of colon in variable declaration

Tags: python

I was asked recently what this means in Python:

`>>> char : str`

I had no idea. I checked the docs and there isn't anything like that.  One suggestion was that it is static type declaration, but there is absolutely nothing in the docs about that either.

With the above, if I
`>>> type(char)` it fails

If I `>>> char : str = 'abc'` it works, and the results of type(char) is `<class: str>`.  It can't be static declaration though, because I can `>>> char : str = 4` and type(char) becomes `<class: int>`.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You are looking at an *annotation* for a variable. The hint is moved to the `__annotations__` mapping:

```
>>> char: str
>>> __annotations__
{'char': <class 'str'>}
```

Variable annotations are there to support third-party tooling, such as type checkers; the syntax is new in Python 3.6.

See [PEP 526 -- *Syntax for Variable Annotations*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), and [*What's new in Python 3.6*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep526):

> Just as for function annotations, the Python interpreter does not attach any particular meaning to variable annotations and only stores them in the `__annotations__` attribute of a class or module.

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like it started in 3.5. >.<  Guess I missed this one.  https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html?highlight=hint#whatsnew-pep-484

Comment: @Jaberwocky: 3.5 added type hinting, but the *variable annotation* syntax you used is specific to Python 3.6. (don't get confused with annotations in function definitions, those have been part of Python 3 since version 3.0).

Comment: it's typing hints in Python, For more information, please refer to: 
    https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#module-typing

Comment: @BinLee: no, it's *annotations*. Type hints build on top of Python's annotations model, and it was certainly an important driver of extending annotations to variables, but it is not the same thing. You are free to use the same syntax for other purposes.