# What is the purpose of using " -> int" after a function def in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int
```

This is function name and  this format is used in python. I am confused why we are using this arrow and why we are using `int` inside paranthesis after `s`. Can someone explain please?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51639332/3001761. Note that "this" is a pretty terrible description for a title.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21384492/635608

Comment: In the future, please use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions. Use a version-specific tag at your discretion

Answer (score 3):

They are function annotations.

`->` marks the return function annotation indicating the function returns an `int`.

The `: str` indicates a string argument.

You can read more about them [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Or, SO: [What does -> mean in Python function definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379753/what-does-mean-in-python-function-definitions)

Comment: Questions that you know to be duplicative should be closed, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), including the bullet point regarding questions that "have already been asked and answered many times before".